# How to perform logical shift(PSLLDQ) within 128 bit SSE Registers in GAS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, gnu-assembler

I want to perform [PSLLDQ](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pslldq) instruction in GAS Assembly to shift arbitrary bytes within 128 bit SSE registers.

```
    pslldq $13, %xmm14    # performs shift left by 13 bytes within xmm14
```

Now, this instruction is working while I am using a imm8 as one of the operand.

But, I want to shift left arbitrary arbitrary length (Can't be 13 all the time).

```
    movq     $16,      %rax        # store 16 in rax
    sub      %rdx,     %rax        # rax = rax - rdx, let's assume rdx = 3
    movq     %rax,     %xmm10      # xmm10 = 13

    pslldq   %xmm10,   %xmm14      # try to shift left by 13 bytes
```

Unfortunately this instruction is not working.... The error is as follows:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `pslldq'
```

I am new to this GAS Assembly. Please let me how can I fix this.

Is there any alternatives to reach my goal?

Comment: No such instruction exists.  Consider using `pshufb` with a mask of (16-x, 17-x, ..., 31-x) which you can build quickly.

Comment: Really!! Anyway...  how pshufb can be used to reach the same goal?  I didn't actually get the whole idea. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: What more elaboration do you need?  I already showed you what index vector to use.